# Certificate error connecting to a Kubernet cluster behind a firewall

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubernetes-dashboard

I have a bare metal Kubernete cluster running behind a firewall. When trying to connect to it from my local machine (on the other side of the firewall) the connection do not work because the certificate is not correct. 
The problem is the following. The cluster runs inside a network behind the firewall and the certificate was created using the master IP. But when I use this same certificate trying to connect from outside the internal network, I use a differente IP. At this point the error message appears, saying that the certificate is different from the address I am trying to connect.

The IP that I use to access the cluster is different from the actual cluster IP displayed here:
[image]

How can I fix it? Is it possible to create another certificate with a different IP in my master node?

Answer (score 1):

You can add new Subject Alternative Names (SANs) to your Kubernetes API server certificate with the following steps.

First need your `kubeadm` configuration file. This creates a file named `kubeadm.yaml`:

`kubectl -n kube-system get configmap kubeadm-config -o jsonpath='{.data.ClusterConfiguration}' > kubeadm.yaml`

Now open the file in an editor, and find the `certSANs` list under the `apiServer` section. If it does not exist, you’ll need to add it; if so, you’ll just add another entry to that list. Example:

```
apiServer:
  certSANs:
  - "172.29.50.162"
  - "k8s.domain.com"
  - "other-k8s.domain.net"
  extraArgs:
    authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
```

Now move the old certificates to another folder, otherwise `kubeadm` will not recreate new ones:

`mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.{crt,key} ~`

Use `kubeadm` to generate new apiserver certificates:

`kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --config kubeadm.yaml`

Now restart your *kubeapiserver* container:

1. Run `docker ps | grep kube-apiserver | grep -v pause` to get the
   container ID for the container running the Kubernetes API server
2. Run `docker kill <containerID>` to kill the container.
3. *The Kubelet will automatically restart the container, which will pick up the new certificate.*

If everything is working as expected, don't forget to update the `kubeadm` ConfigMap stored in the cluster, otherwise, future `kubeadm` upgrade will be lacking your new config:

`kubeadm config upload from-file --config kubeadm.yaml`

*This article has a more complete guide on how to [Adding a Name to the Kubernetes API Server Certificate](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2019/07/30/adding-a-name-to-kubernetes-api-server-certificate/)*